# Condition for pointwise convergence of $({f_n}')_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ to $f'$ if $({f_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges pointwise to $f$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Problem**

> Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of differentiable functions such that $f_n:A(\subseteq \mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges pointwise to a differentiable function $f$. If $({f_n}')_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ also converges pointwise to $g$ and $g$ satisfies the intermediate value property prove or disprove that $f'=g$.

For the example given [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiynLXE1fzPAhWLOY8KHeD5DzoQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ucdavis.edu%2F~hunter%2Fm125a%2Fintro_analysis_ch5.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHe_wbpc0fH7O0uHigRujRH0RfwfA) (see page no. 63, **Example 5.17**) $g$ doesn't satisfy the intermediate value property and hence doesn't meet the condition of the problem.

Can anyone help me in proving or disproving it?

Comment: It would be good to summarize the main results concerning that example in your question. For one thing, links can go bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The function $h(x) =\int_0^x \sin (1/t)\,dt$ is differentiable everywhere, with $h'(x) = \sin (1/x)$ for $x\ne 0$ by the FTC, and $h'(0)=0$ because of all the oscillation at $0.$ (You have to do some work to see this last bit. ) Now you have mentioned an example of a sequence $f_n$ converging to $0$ uniformly on $\mathbb R,$ such that $f_n'$ converges pointwise to $g = \chi_{\{0\}}.$ For your problem here, consider the functions $f_n + h.$

Answer (score 0):

Since $f_0,f_1,f_2,...f_n$ is continuous and differentiable $n$-times, we say it is of multiplicity $n$.

We say $\alpha$ is a Zero (root) of multiplicity n $\ni f(\alpha)=f'(\alpha)= f^2(\alpha)=... f^{n-1}(\alpha)$

Since the sequence converges to $1$ limit point, $g \rightarrow f$ is a contracting function.

By the intermediate value theorem, there exists an $\alpha \in [1,n] \ni \frac{f(1)-f(n)}{1-n}=f'(\alpha)$

$\frac{f(1)-f(n)}{1-n}$ converges to a limit point $g$.

Hence $g=f'$.

(I have used the theory of numerical solutions of non linear equations)

Comment: Is this an answer to the question?